# Android Object указать тип и получить доступ к методам

Tags: java, android

Есть массив, в котором могут храниться объекты разных типов:

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(new Matrix());
objects.add(new Path());
```

Это, конечно, здорово, но почему я не могу напрямую изменять каждый элемент?

```
(Matrix)(objects.get(0)).postScale(2, 2);    // postScale красненьким
(Path)(objects.get(1)).transform(objects.get(0));    //transform красненьким
```

Ведь, указав тип объекта (в скобках), я получаю объект этого типа. Почему же тогда нет доступа к его методам? Что за безобразие?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не правильно расставили скобки при привидении типов, должно быть так:

```
((Matrix)objects.get(0)).postScale(2, 2);
((Path)objects.get(1)).transform(objects.get(0));
```

Comment: ах ну надо же! кто бы мог подумать!

Comment: Синтаксически код конечно же верный, но вот концептуально... За такой код меня в юности били по башке долго и упорно пока не отучили от операции каста надолго если не насовсем. Приведение типов в Java это всегда только крайняя мера.

Comment: @Barmaley не спорю что решение со списком Object'ов ужасное, но это автору решать. Я всего лишь показал как правильно сделать так что бы работало.

Comment: ну может таки показать МЧ как надо делать в Java style?